# Create a function pointer which takes a function pointer as an argument

Tags: c++, function-pointers

How to create a function pointer which takes a function pointer as an argument (c++)???
i have this code

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int kvadrat (int a)
{
    return a*a;
}
int kub (int a)
{
    return a*a*a;
}
void centralna (int a, int (*pokfunk) (int))
{
    int rezultat=(*pokfunk) (a);
    cout<<rezultat<<endl;

}

void main ()
{
    int a;
    cout<<"unesite broj"<<endl;
    cin>>a;
    int (*pokfunk) (int) = 0;
    if (a<10)
        pokfunk=&kub;
    if (a>=10)
        pokfunk=&kvadrat;

    void (*cent) (int, int*)=&centralna; // here i have to create a pointer to the function "centralna" and call the function by its pointer

    system ("pause");
}
```

Comment: You might want to consider keeping your variable names in English. It will be easier for foreign (to you) programmers to understand your code. And I am not just talking about native English speaking programmers. Just a thought.

Comment: yeah i know, i had translated it but i pasted this code by accident, i've just noticed it. but the reply's helped alot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the function pointer type as the type of the parameter:

```
void (*cent) (int, int (*)(int)) = &centralna
```

Answer (score 8):

you will find it easier to typedef function pointers.

```
typedef int (*PokFunc)(int);
typedef void (*CentralnaFunc)(int, PokFunc);
...
CentralnaFunc cf = &centralna;
```

Comment: this is very useful, but im not yet alowed to use it

Comment: You're forgetting "best" may be defined to include "complies to unspecified requirements".

Comment: @GMan: You've spent enough time on here to know what the purpose of the answer feature is, but thanks for your input.

Comment: Yes, it's the answer the *questioner* finds most helpful. And "helpful" may include anything the questioner wants, including compliance to certain specifications, made public or not. I agree `typedef`'s are the best way to go (I always tell others to use more `typedef`'s), but this answer is not helpful *to the questioner*. No biggie, you'll still get plenty of up-votes by people who agree with the answer, like me.

Answer (score 2):

`void (*cent)(int,`**`int (*) (int)`**`)=&centralna;`